# How to measure per user bandwidth usage on google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud

We want to charge users based on the amount of traffic their data has. Actually the amount of downstream bandwidth their data is consuming.

I have exported google cloud storage access_logs. From the logs, I can count the number of times a file is accessed. (filesize * count will be the bandwidth usage)

But the problem is that this doesn't work well with cached content. My calculated value is much more than the actual usage.

I went with this method because our traffic will be new and won't use the cache, which means that the difference won't matter. But in reality, it seems like it is a real problem.

This is a common use case and I think there should be a better way to solve this problem with google cloud storage.

```
{
  "insertId": "-tohip8e1vmvw",
  "logName": "projects/bucket/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "granted": true,
        "permission": "storage.objects.get",
        "resource": "projects/_/bucket/bucket.appspot.com/objects/users/2y7aPImLYeTsCt6X0dwNMlW9K5h1/somefile",
        "resourceAttributes": {}
      },
      {
        "granted": true,
        "permission": "storage.objects.getIamPolicy",
        "resource": "projects/_/bucket/bucket.appspot.com/objects/users/2y7aPImLYeTsCt6X0dwNMlW9K5h1/somefile",
        "resourceAttributes": {}
      }
    ],
    "methodName": "storage.objects.get",
    "requestMetadata": {
      "destinationAttributes": {},
      "requestAttributes": {
        "auth": {},
        "time": "2019-07-02T11:58:36.068Z"
      }
    },
    "resourceLocation": {
      "currentLocations": [
        "eu"
      ]
    },
    "resourceName": "projects/_/bucket/bucket.appspot.com/objects/users/2y7aPImLYeTsCt6X0dwNMlW9K5h1/somefile",
    "serviceName": "storage.googleapis.com",
    "status": {}
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2019-07-02T11:58:36.412798307Z",
  "resource": {
    "labels": {
      "bucket_name": "bucket.appspot.com",
      "location": "eu",
      "project_id": "project-id"
    },
    "type": "gcs_bucket"
  },
  "severity": "INFO",
  "timestamp": "2019-07-02T11:58:36.062Z"
}
```

An entry of the log.

We are using a single bucket for now. Can also use multiple if it helps.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but something you may be interested in considering: Requester Pays (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/requester-pays)

Comment: According to the documentation regarding [Cloud Storage Object Metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata), GCS objects have metadata associated with them, so I recommend that you factor them into your implementation.

Comment: Thanks ... I found one solution but it requires me to have a separate bucket for each user.  Will post the answer in a while :)

Comment: lol i can't answer myself..
It's the stackdriver timeseries api. (Actually the same thing how google shows bucket usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to have a separate bucket for each user and get the bucket's bandwidth usage through [timeseries api](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/TimeSeries).

The endpoint for this purpose is:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list

And following are the parameters to achieve bytes sent for one hour (we can specify time range above 60s) whose sum will be the total bytes sent from the bucket.

```
{
  "dataSets": [
    {
      "timeSeriesFilter": {
        "filter": "metric.type=\"storage.googleapis.com/network/sent_bytes_count\" resource.type=\"gcs_bucket\" resource.label.\"project_id\"=\"<<<< project id here >>>>\" resource.label.\"bucket_name\"=\"<<<< bucket name here >>>>\"",
        "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_SUM",
        "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_SUM",
        "secondaryCrossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_SUM",
        "minAlignmentPeriod": "3600s",
        "groupByFields": [
          "resource.label.\"bucket_name\""
        ],
        "unitOverride": "By"
      },
      "targetAxis": "Y1",
      "plotType": "LINE",
      "legendTemplate": "${resource.labels.bucket_name}"
    }
  ],
  "options": {
    "mode": "COLOR"
  },
  "constantLines": [],
  "timeshiftDuration": "0s",
  "y1Axis": {
    "label": "y1Axis",
    "scale": "LINEAR"
  }
}
```